# Compare two values in document and display the common values in each row in result

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have documents in which am storing two main objects scan and result, I want the output such that in result I get separate row for each match of scan.location and result.location.

**Date:**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6024d02a1bf5152b44baf521"),
    "scan" : {
        "customerId" : "e2565eac-2086-48fc-ba18-dbce74602e22",
        "customerGenderSelection" : "F",
        "scanQuery" : {
            "service" : "MA",
            "date" : "08-Nov-2020",
            "locations" : [ 
                {
                    "locationId" : "0023",
                    "locationName" : "dobson"
                }, 
                {
                    "locationId" : "0001",
                    "locationName" : "shea"
                }
            ]
        },
        "sessionId" : "70511849-97f8-4318-a96e-bb3a573c52ea",
    },
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "employeeId" : "224f55b2-27bc-4e34-8249-a8d201540ac2",
            "time" : "11:00",
            "locationId" : "0023"
        }, 
        {
            "employeeId" : "224f55b2-27bc-4e34-8249-a8d201540ac2",
            "time" : "12:00",
            "locationId" : "0023"
        }, 
        {
            "employeeId" : "224f55b2-27bc-4e34-8249-a8d201540ac2",
            "time" : "12:30",
            "locationId" : "0023"
        }, 
        {
            "employeeId" : "224f55b2-27bc-4e34-8249-a8d201540ac2",
            "time" : "13:00",
            "locationId" : "0001"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want result where scan.scanQuery.locations.locationId == result.locationId.  So expecting a result in the below format:

**Expected Response:**

```
{
    "scan" : {
        "customerId" : "e2565eac-2086-48fc-ba18-dbce74602e22",
        "customerGenderSelection" : "F",
        "scanQuery" : {
            "service" : "MA",
            "date" : "08-Nov-2020",
            "locations" : [ 
                {
                    "locationId" : "0023",
                    "locationName" : "dobson"
                }
            ]
        },
        "sessionId" : "70511849-97f8-4318-a96e-bb3a573c52ea",
    },
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "employeeId" : "224f55b2-27bc-4e34-8249-a8d201540ac2",
            "time" : "11:00",
            "locationId" : "0023"
        }, 
        {
            "employeeId" : "224f55b2-27bc-4e34-8249-a8d201540ac2",
            "time" : "12:00",
            "locationId" : "0023"
        }, 
        {
            "employeeId" : "224f55b2-27bc-4e34-8249-a8d201540ac2",
            "time" : "12:30",
            "locationId" : "0023"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "scan" : {
        "customerId" : "e2565eac-2086-48fc-ba18-dbce74602e22",
        "customerGenderSelection" : "F",
        "scanQuery" : {
            "service" : "MA",
            "date" : "08-Nov-2020",
            "locations" : 
                {
                    "locationId" : "0001",
                    "locationName" : "shea"
                }
            ]
        },
        "sessionId" : "70511849-97f8-4318-a96e-bb3a573c52ea",
    },
    "result" : [         
        {
            "employeeId" : "224f55b2-27bc-4e34-8249-a8d201540ac2",
            "time" : "13:00",
            "locationId" : "0001"
        }
    ]
}
```

Any suggestions or ideas would be helpful.

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/eq/ either in aggregation query or using https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/ in find query

Comment: I am new to mongodb, I have tried a lot of ways using aggregation's unwind, project and eq and also expr, but unable to get the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
db.locations.aggregate([
    {
        $unwind: "$scan.scanQuery.locations"
    },
    {
        $addFields: {
            result: {
                $filter: {
                    input: "$result",
                    as: "item",
                    cond: { 
                        $eq: ["$scan.scanQuery.locations.locationId", "$$item.locationId"]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
]);
```

Output:

```js
{
  "_id": ObjectId("6024d02a1bf5152b44baf521"),
  "scan": {
    "customerId": "e2565eac-2086-48fc-ba18-dbce74602e22",
    "customerGenderSelection": "F",
    "scanQuery": {
      "service": "MA",
      "date": "08-Nov-2020",
      "locations": {
        "locationId": "0023",
        "locationName": "dobson"
      }
    },
    "sessionId": "70511849-97f8-4318-a96e-bb3a573c52ea"
  },
  "result": [
    {
      "employeeId": "224f55b2-27bc-4e34-8249-a8d201540ac2",
      "time": "11:00",
      "locationId": "0023"
    },
    {
      "employeeId": "224f55b2-27bc-4e34-8249-a8d201540ac2",
      "time": "12:00",
      "locationId": "0023"
    },
    {
      "employeeId": "224f55b2-27bc-4e34-8249-a8d201540ac2",
      "time": "12:30",
      "locationId": "0023"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "_id": ObjectId("6024d02a1bf5152b44baf521"),
  "scan": {
    "customerId": "e2565eac-2086-48fc-ba18-dbce74602e22",
    "customerGenderSelection": "F",
    "scanQuery": {
      "service": "MA",
      "date": "08-Nov-2020",
      "locations": {
        "locationId": "0001",
        "locationName": "shea"
      }
    },
    "sessionId": "70511849-97f8-4318-a96e-bb3a573c52ea"
  },
  "result": [
    {
      "employeeId": "224f55b2-27bc-4e34-8249-a8d201540ac2",
      "time": "13:00",
      "locationId": "0001"
    }
  ]
}
```